# is there an emacs interface to a relational database?

Tags: database, sqlite, emacs

I need to enter many text fields in this database and was looking to enter them through a form like you might create in MS Access or Open/LibreOffice's Database. Is there such a template-generating package for emacs that would talk to one of such databases (or possibly SQLite)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is emacs widget.  For example: http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/beta/html/widget_3.html. Here is the user interface. http://www.xemacs.org/Documentation/beta/html/widget_2.html#SEC2.  This also works with gnu-emacs.
You might want to write some code that it can insert the data in your database, via SQL.   Also look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sql-transform.el.  I personally would like to have insert the data via org-mode tables.

Comment: Yes, this is something like I had in mind (the widgets). But for XEmacs, really?? :) I used to be a devotee of XEmacs...

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you create a simple text file from the entered data which you then can convert to SQL format and import into the database?

Comment: Maybe because that would mean three discrete steps (enter data, convert data, import into the database), instead of having data entry and import handled from Emacs at the same time, with no extra conversion step?

Comment: Yes, but it's a feasible alternative if there is no direct DB access, isn't it? And the conversion step is trivial to implement and automate, so the user doing the data entry from emacs wouldn't know the difference at all.

Comment: If there's no direct access you don't have many options, do you? But if there is, setting Emacs up to act as an sql front end (similar to MSAccess) would be much nicer I think. Especially if you want to update and delete data, as well as enter it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question; if you need clarification on the motive for the question, that can be done in a comment instead.